# Where can I ask questions about writing documentation?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Where can I ask questions about writing the types of documentation listed below?

- Requirements
- Architecture/Design
- Technical
- End User
- Marketing

Comment: *"ask questions for documentation"* .. what kind of questions?

Comment: What kind of documentation?

Comment: I mean the format , guidelines , usages and how to write a well documentation , answered by experiences ! If I will write a documentation , what kind of usage should I avoid and if I can show some part of  my documentation , want to know which is illegal and how to correct it :)

Comment: @Dave Newton , I'm currently writing  End User Documentation :)

Comment: argh, there has been a question about this before here on Meta. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: Project Management ? OR User Experience ?

Comment: @zey I don't recall, but I remember answering something similar stating "Nah, doesn't fit anywhere" with (I think) Monical Cellio coming in and pointing at the Writers SE beta. http://writers.stackexchange.com/ Their FAQ seems to indicate that questions regarding "technical [...] writing" are welcome. But I know far too little to be sure. So check it out, but don't take my word for it.

Comment: This is the one you're talking about @bart: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158495/where-to-ask-about-writing-docs-for-a-library, not _certain_ it's a dupe...

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards YES! I knew there was something. Not exactly a dupe indeed.

Comment: All questions about asking where to post should come with the example/exact post. Otherwise you're just talking topics, and that all depends